# maximum gyroUpdateInterval

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

I can find no specific number for the maximum frequency of updates that iPhone allows for gyroscope. [The documentation for gyroUpdateInterval](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/gyroUpdateInterval) says:

> The value of this property is capped to minimum and maximum values; the maximum value is determined by the maximum frequency supported by the hardware.

I cannot find a number for this cap.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it depends on the hardware. The easiest way to get a rough guess is to set it something very large (infinity) and very small (0) and measure the update rate.